# Alsaaudio module, recording for specific amount of time

Tags: audio, python, alsa, recording

The below code records the audio for some time (I don't know how much)
How to calculate the total time of its recording?

For example, if I want to record for just one minute then how would I limit its time?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

## recordtest.py
##
## This is an example of a simple sound capture script.
##
## The script opens an ALSA pcm forsound capture. Set
## various attributes of the capture, and reads in a loop,
## writing the data to standard out.
##
## To test it out do the following:
## python recordtest.py out.raw # talk to the microphone
## aplay -r 8000 -f S16_LE -c 1 out.raw


# Footnote: I'd normally use print instead of sys.std(out|err).write,
# but we're in the middle of the conversion between python 2 and 3
# and this code runs on both versions without conversion

import sys
import time
import getopt
import alsaaudio

def usage():
    sys.stderr.write('usage: recordtest.py [-c <card>] <file>\n')
    sys.exit(2)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    card = 'sysdefault:CARD=Device'

    opts, args = getopt.getopt(sys.argv[1:], 'c:')
    for o, a in opts:
        if o == '-c':
            card = a

    if not args:
        usage()

    f = open(args[0], 'wb')

    # Open the device in nonblocking capture mode. The last argument could
    # just as well have been zero for blocking mode. Then we could have
    # left out the sleep call in the bottom of the loop
    inp = alsaaudio.PCM(alsaaudio.PCM_CAPTURE, alsaaudio.PCM_NONBLOCK, card)

    # Set attributes: Mono, 44100 Hz, 16 bit little endian samples
    inp.setchannels(1)
    inp.setrate(44100)
    inp.setformat(alsaaudio.PCM_FORMAT_S16_LE)

    # The period size controls the internal number of frames per period.
    # The significance of this parameter is documented in the ALSA api.
    # For our purposes, it is suficcient to know that reads from the device
    # will return this many frames. Each frame being 2 bytes long.
    # This means that the reads below will return either 320 bytes of data
    # or 0 bytes of data. The latter is possible because we are in nonblocking
    # mode.
    inp.setperiodsize(160)

    loops = 1000000
    while loops > 0:
        loops -= 1
        # Read data from device
        l, data = inp.read()

        if l:
            f.write(data)
            time.sleep(.001)
```

Comment: I have a good solution for you, may be you want to write software that work with sound, if you want direct program alsa, it's bad idea, because it's also hard work and doesn't multi platform, Windows has its driver, mac has itself driver, you should do such as vlc programer : use http://portaudio.com library. it implemented by c, by you can use in python.

Comment: portaudio for python: http://people.csail.mit.edu/hubert/pyaudio/

Comment: please read carefully this big picture: http://portaudio.com/docs/v19-doxydocs/portaudio-external-architecture-diagram.png

Comment: could you please look into this thread, http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/92854/pyaudio-modile-getting-error-running-the-default-example-program

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In every second, you record 44100 frames (or whatever sample rate you have set).

Just add up the number of frames read, and stop when you have recorded 60*44100 of them:

```py
total = 0
while total < 60 * 44100:
    l, data = inp.read()
    if l:
        total += l
        f.write(data)
        time.sleep(.001)
```

Comment: I am trying to understand what you said, could you please elaborate a bit ?